# Orange custom widget

Tags: python, widget, data-mining, orange

I am trying to get the example given in [Orange Development Tutorial](http://orange-development.readthedocs.org/tutorial-cont.html) to work with version 2.7. However, while I am able to test my widget from the Python shell, I can't get the custom widget that I generate to show up in the Orange Canvas GUI. All I see is a Demo bar with nothing underneath.

I used `pip install -e .` to install this package and I see that a link was created under `*PATH_TO_PYTHON2.7*/site-packages/`

Any suggestions ?

Comment: The documentation in your link is for Orange 3. For Orange2.7 use: http://docs.orange.biolab.si/extend-widgets/rst/index.html.

Comment: Thanks ! I followed the instructions on that page and the result is the same. I see a Demo tab but no widgets show up.